# How to create a Rails test for duplicate email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, enums

I'm trying to use Rspec to test a model. The `User` model has method that will assign a role to it:

```
after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

def set_default_role
  self.role ||= :admin
end
```

How could I write a test for it? Please note that I'm Mongoid and Mongoid::Enum (the role is an enum field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two specs for making sure this is assigned when initialized.

```
context "role" do
    let(:bob) { User.new }
    let(:alice) { User.new(role: :manager) }

    it "assigns default role" do
      expect(bob.role).to eq(:admin)
    end

    it "doesn't override role" do
      expect(alice.role).to eq(:manager)
    end
end
```

---

You can also [use the `default` option](https://github.com/thetron/mongoid-enum#default-value) to specify the default value of `:role`.

```
enum :role, [:manager, :admin], default: :admin
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be testing a simple case of if a new user is assigned the string value 'admin' on initialization.

```
it 'is assigned default role' do
  expect(User.new(:valid_params).role).to eq 'admin'
end
```

If you want to test that it's persisted after creation, you can do

```
 it 'is assigned default role' do
   User.create(:valid_params)      
   expect(User.first.role).to eq 'admin'
end
```